# Incompatible types - Found Object when using generics

Tags: java

I'm having an issue where the following loop is throwing an error `Incompatible types: Required: Workstation, Found: java.lang.Object`.

With everything being typed, I can't understand why it's finding an Object instead of the typed object.

```
private static WorkflowProcess getWorkflowProcessByWorkstationRecursive(Collection<WorkflowProcess> workflowProcesses) {
    for (WorkflowProcess workflowProcess : workflowProcesses) {
        for (Workstation workstation : workflowProcess.getWorkstations()) //ERROR IS HERE
```

**WorkflowProcess.java**

```
abstract public class WorkflowProcess<WorkstationType extends Workstation> {

    private ArrayList<WorkstationType> workstationList = new ArrayList<WorkstationType>();

    public ArrayList<WorkstationType> getWorkstations() {
        return workstationList;
    }
```

**ServerWorkflowProcess.java**

```
abstract public class ServerWorkflowProcess extends WorkflowProcess<ServerWorkstation> {
```

**ServerWorkstation.java**

```
abstract public class ServerWorkstation extends Workstation<ServerWorkflowProcess> {
```

It gets a little complicated, but essentially the class hierarchy looks like this:

`SpecificWorkflowProcess` extends `TypeOfWorkflowProcess<TypeOfWorkstaton>` extends `WorkflowProcess`

`SpecificWorkstation` extends `TypeOfWorkstation<TypeOfWorkflowProcess>` extends `Workstation`

`WorkflowProcesses` to `Workstation` = One to many

Comment: `WorkflowProcess#getWorkstations()` declaration?

Comment: Generally it's best to start with the first error *or warning* in the file first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the *raw* type `WorkflowProcess`. That means that the API you get is effectively the *erasure* of the normal API, so the return type of `getWorkstations` becomes just `ArrayList`.

You can fix this easily as:

```
private static WorkflowProcess getWorkflowProcessByWorkstationRecursive(
    Collection<WorkflowProcess<?>> workflowProcesses) {
  for (WorkflowProcess<?> workflowProcess : workflowProcesses) {
    ..
  }
}
```

By using the wildcarding, you're basically saying "I know that generics are involved here, but I don't actually mind what the `WorkstationType` type parameter is in the collection".

Comment: If I know that the list will always `extend Workstation` on some level, is it best to always do a `? extends Workstation` ?

Comment: @Webnet: You already know that because it's in the description for the `WorkstationType` type parameter... it's not like it could be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the generic parameter to the type of `workflowProcess`in the second line:

```
private static WorkflowProcess getWorkflowProcessByWorkstationRecursive(Collection<WorkflowProcess> workflowProcesses) {
    for (WorkflowProcess<Workstation> workflowProcess : workflowProcesses) {
        for (Workstation workstation : workflowProcess.getWorkstations())
```